# Programatically show wait icon in ListView Aurelia KendoUI

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, aurelia

In one of the [solutions](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-manually-show-and-hide-loading-or-spinning-image), they said:

```
 $('<div class="k-loading-mask" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="k-loading-text">Loading...</span><div class="k-loading-image"></div><div class="k-loading-color"></div></div>')
        .appendTo('#listview .k-grid-content');
```

It doesnt seem to work, Couldnt get it to work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: A bit more context would help. "In one of the solutions" -- could you post a URL to that solution?

Comment: This solution looks a little fishy, you wouldn't interpolate HTML in Aurelia, you'd end up with escaped HTML. You want to use actual HTML with bindings...

Comment: @ToddPrice added the link in question

Comment: @Charleh - Do you have a better solution?

Comment: There are a million solutions in that thread you posted. Did you try some of the others? A more aurelia way to do it would be to add a wrapper div to the control which had the loading indicator styles on and hide/show that when your data is loading (you can add/remove a class via interpolation)